# Writing huge strings in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, file-io

I have a very long string, almost a megabyte long, that I need to write to a text file. The regular

```
file = open("file.txt","w")
file.write(string)
file.close()
```

works but is too slow, is there a way I can write faster?

I am trying to write a several million digit number to a text file 
the number is on the order of `math.factorial(67867957)`

This is what shows on profiling:

```
    203 function calls (198 primitive calls) in 0.001 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:217(compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:273(_compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:172(_compile_charset)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:201(_optimize_charset)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:25(_identityfunction)
      3/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:33(_compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:341(_compile_info)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:442(isstring)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:445(_code)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:460(compile)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:126(__len__)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:130(__getitem__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:138(append)
      3/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:140(getwidth)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:178(__init__)
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:183(__next)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:202(match)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:208(get)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:351(_parse_sub)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:429(_parse)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:67(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:726(fix_flags)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:738(parse)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:90(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method compile}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method exec}
       17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method isinstance}
    39/38    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method len}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method max}
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method min}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method ord}
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'find' of 'bytearray' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
```

Comment: Have you considered encoding it yourself first, and then writing it in binary mode?

Comment: megabyte is not "huge". Are you sure your disk can work faster than python writes? Could your provide a standalone benchmark e.g., `python3 -c'open('file', 'w').write("a"*1000000)'` What time does it on your computer? What is the desired time?

Comment: Well I know it's not huge but it's large enough to take a long time in my laptop computer. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it's really slow, taking hours to write. But then again, I'm just a beginner and probably am doing something wrong here

Comment: lol there is no way it should take hours to write 1 MB ... it should take at most a few seconds (and thats being generous) ... as @J.F.Sebastian mentions please profile it with something simple...

Comment: If you have a computer that can run a modern web browser, then you have a computer that can write 1MB to disk quickly enough. If your program is taking a long time to run, then something else is the bottleneck. Find out what that bottleneck is.

Comment: Well... Where are you getting this String from.... ? Don't tell me that it is from some HTTP API call.

Comment: as @JoranBeasley mentioned it can't be that long... must be another problem.  maybe the so called string isn't what you expect?

Comment: I know, that's what I think is weird, my laptop is not that slow. I don't know if is something of my code but my code uses the regular way I showed before, I don't know if it's because is just one variable that is that long and this is the problem, all I know is that is taking too long and using almost all my RAM

Comment: I'm calculating a primorial of a large prime (product of all primes less than or equal to a number) that's where the string comes from. Could it be that it's taking so long no to write but to  convert from integer to string?

Comment: I suspect the calculation is what takes a long time ... not the writing to disk (isnt that essentially RSA encryption cracking ... which takes until the heat death of the universe?) the conversion to string is also certainly not what takes a long time

Comment: Well, the calculation is already made, I made it print all the time it makes a multiplication so I can keep track of it and the calculation for the prime I inputed is done (yes, I want to use that later for research in security and RSA cracking but no, I'm not cracking right now)

Comment: I guarantee the calculation is what is taking forever ... not the converting to string, nor the writing to disc.... you can verify this easily by saving the calculation in a variable and printing the len(str(my_var)) abd how long it took ... and then writing `str(my_var)` to file

Comment: I am keeping track of every time it does a calculation and I can garantee that the calculation is over, my output is that is a really long number which I want to write to a file and is taking forever. The calculation did take a very long time but I made the computer print every time it went thru the loop the number in which it were in, the last number printed was the last number it had to go thru

Comment: What does your profiling show? https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: All I see is `0.001 Seconds` .

Comment: @tristan: `profile` measures CPU time. It is probably not appropriate to measure I/O performance.

Comment: note: `/usr/bin/time python3 -c'open("/tmp/file", "w").write("a"*500*1000000)'` takes under a second on my machine. OS probably uses a file cache in memory. `ls -l /tmp/file` confirms 500M file.

Comment: Maybe the conversion to string would be quicker if you used the `Decimal` module for the calculations?

Comment: Seriously.... Can you calculate `math.factorial(67867957)` on your machine ? Isn't `Factorial(20)` the last factorial to be in `64-bits`. And `34!` is `128 bit`

Comment: It's not factorial, it's primorial but grows almost as fast, but yes, the calculation is already done

Comment: even though its a lousy answer im leaving my answer for now ...

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Python 3 doesn't have fixed-size integers - everything is a bignum. It might take a damned long time, but yes, you can calculate `math.factorial(67867957)`.

Comment: @senshin try it on your machine. I don't think every machine will agree.

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley for the help. I'm not sure there is a way to go faster, I guess I will just have to wait and get over it.

Comment: have you tried `pickle.dump(n, file)` or `n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')` instead of `str(n)`? In general, `gmpy2` may be faster for large integers (millions of digits).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian no, I haven't will give it a try

Comment: `/usr/bin/time python -c'import gmpy2; open("/tmp/file", "w").write(str(gmpy2.fac(67867957)))'` takes less than 10 minutes on my machine. `/tmp/file` contains 500M digits number

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian that sounds like the beginning of an answer to me.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian dang you should really put that as an answer ... as now that this quesiton  has been more fully flushed out it may actually be usefull

Comment: FWIW, the maintainer of [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2), Case Van Horsen, is an [SO member](http://stackoverflow.com/users/224574/casevh).

Comment: it seems [`str(n)` is a quadratic operation in Python](http://bugs.python.org/issue3451#msg84704). `python3 -c'import math; open("/tmp/file2", "w").write(str(math.factorial(678679
57)))'` is still running after 12 hours. For comparison: `pickle.dump(math.factorial(67867957), open("/tmp/file3.pickle", "wb"))` took 6 hours (`pickle.dump` along takes less than a second).

Comment: As answered by @J.F.Sebastian, the fundamental issue is that `str(long)` has quadratic running time. I am biased since I maintain `gmpy2`, but if you plan to work with such huge numbers, you really should be using 'gmpy2`. BTW, the current development version (2.1.x) includes the `primorial` function.  `gmpy2.primorial(67867957)` takes about 3.5 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that `str(long)` is very slow for large intergers (millions of digits) in Python. [It is a quadratic operation (in number of digits) in Python](http://bugs.python.org/issue3451#msg84704) i.e., for ~1e8 digits it may require ~1e16 operations to convert the integer to a decimal string.

Writing to a file 500MB should not take hours e.g.:

```
$ python3 -c 'open("file", "w").write("a"*500*1000000)'
```

returns almost immediately. `ls -l file` confirms that the file is created and it has the expected size.

Calculating `math.factorial(67867957)` (the result has ~500M digits) may take several hours but saving it using `pickle` is instantaneous:

```
import math
import pickle

n = math.factorial(67867957) # takes a long time
with open("file.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(n, file) # very fast (comparatively)
```

To load it back using `n = pickle.load(open('file.pickle', 'rb'))` takes less than a second.

*`str(n)` is still running (after 50 hours) on my machine.*

To get the decimal representation fast, you could [use `gmpy2`](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mpz.html):

```
$ python -c'import gmpy2;open("file.gmpy2", "w").write(str(gmpy2.fac(67867957)))'
```

It takes less than 10 minutes on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

ok this is really not an answer it is more to prove your reasoning for the delay wrong

first test write speed of a big string

```
 import timeit
 def write_big_str(n_bytes=1000000):
     with open("test_file.txt","wb") as f:
          f.write("a"*n_bytes)
 print timeit.timeit("write_big_str()","from __main__ import write_big_str",number=100)
```

you should see a fairly respectable speed (and thats to repeat it 100 times)

next we will see how long it takes to convert a very big number to a str

```
import timeit,math
n = math.factorial(200000)
print timeit.timeit("str(n)","from __main__ import n",number=1)
```

it will probably take ~10seconds (and that is a million digit number) , which granted is slow ... but not hours slow (ok its pretty slow to convert to string :P... but still shouldnt take hours) (well it took more like 243 seconds for my box i guess :P)

Comment: Here is the thing, 200000! looks tiny compared to the number I'm writing. My number is a bit smaller than 67867957! The python had no problem writing 49979687# (# is symbol for primorial) which is approximately  49979687!

Comment: ahh now we are starting to get helpful data ... indeed the string conversion may take a looooong time ... also that has alot more than a million digits ...

Comment: @JoãoAreias 67867957! is about 500 million decimal digits in length, i.e. we're talking about ~500 MB, not 1 MB.

Comment: Oh, sorry my mistake. I read it wrong when I was going to write here, is not 1MB is more like 100, primorial still smaller than factorial(even though still huge) is there any way of speeding up the process or do I just have to wait and deal with it?

Comment: oh well yeah 100Million digit number will take a while to convert to a string ...

Comment: unrelated: you could pass a function object itself e.g., `timeit.timeit(write_big_str, number=100)/100.`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian dang i learn something new sometimes I guess :P thanks for the tip :)