# Do I loose precision when converting from MPZ to long?

Tags: python, gmpy

I wrote the following modulo exponentiation. But I am not sure if I will loose precision when converting from MPZ type to long.

```
def mypowmod(base, power, modulus):
    base = gmpy.mpz(base)
    power = gmpy.mpz(power)
    modulus = gmpy.mpz(modulus)
    result = pow(base, power, modulus)
    return long(result)
```

Comment: Your function is better written as `mypowmod = pow`.

Comment: @DanD. what do you mean?

Comment: unrelated: if the result has many digits and you want to get a decimal representation (string) then don't convert to `long` and [leave `gmpy2.mpz` as is — `str(mpz)` is *much* faster than `str(long)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of `gmpy` and `gmpy2`.

The Python long type is arbitrary precision. Conversion to/from `long` and `mpz` are always exact.

Since `long` is arbitrary precision, the built-in pow() function will calculate the correct result without requiring the use of `gmpy` or `gmpy2`. However, using the `mpz` type will be much faster. A quick test shows that it is faster even for number of only 10 digits.

```
$ python -m timeit -s "import gmpy;a=10;b=gmpy.mpz('1'*a);p=gmpy.mpz('2'*a)-7;m=gmpy.mpz('3'*a)+11" "pow(b,p,m)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "a=10;b=long('1'*a);p=long('2'*a)-7;m=long('3'*a)+11" "pow(b,p,m)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.89 usec per loop
```

`gmpy` does not have a powmod() function. That function was introduced in `gmpy2`. `gmpy2.powmod` will automatically convert the arguments to `mpz` and return an `mpz` result. Your function could be written as:

```
def mypowmod(base, power, modulus):
    return long(gmpy2.powmod(base, power modulus)
```

Even including the conversion between `long` and `mpz`, it is still much faster than using the built-in `long` type.

```
python -m timeit -s "import gmpy2;a=10;b=long('1'*a);p=long('2'*a)-7;m=long('3'*a)+11" "long(gmpy2.powmod(b,p,m))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

But using the `gmpy.mpz` type is mostly unneeded as the built in `long` type has all the needed operations for this function. The code uses the built in `pow` function rather than say the `gmpy.powmod` function so converting to `gmpy.mpz` is unneeded and as the `pow` function returns a `long` the code becomes:

```
def mypowmod(base, power, modulus):
  result = pow(base, power, modulus)
  return result
```

Which is better written as:

```
mypowmod = pow
```

Comment: If I dont convert the input to MPZ, how can I handle integer size greater than 2^63-1? Could you give a simple example on gmpy.powmod?

Comment: python integers don't have a fixed size.  they can be arbitrarily large.