# Fastest way to generate number like 66666 when the number of digits is given

Tags: python, random, numbers, time-complexity

I have an interesting problem where I want to generate a big number (~30000 digits) but it has to be all identical digits, like `66666666666666.......`

So far I have done this by:

```
def fillWithSixes(digits):
    result = 0
    for i in range(digits):
        result *= 10
        result += 6
    return result
```

However, this is very inefficient, and was wondering if there is any better way? Answer in cpp or java is okay too.

Edit:

1. Let's not just solve for `666666.....` I want it to be generic for any number. How about `7777777777....` or `44444........` or `55555...`?
2. String operations are worse, the increase from current complexity of `O(n)` to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: what do you mean by unique digits.... also, you can instead make `result` a string and concatenate with `result += '6'` then return `int(result)` but if the number is as big as you said, I'm pretty sure that will reach the `int` limit

Comment: or, even better, just `return int('6'*digits)` since `'str'*int = 'strstrstr...'#int times`

Comment: @RNar - python's Ints are arbitrarily big. `int('6' * 10000)` works great.

Comment: [depends on your version of python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the formula `666...666 = 6/9*(10**n-1)`, where n is the number of digits.

So, in Python, you would write that as

```
n = int(input())
a = 6 * (10**n - 1) // 9
print(a)
```

Comment: I found this to be on the order of 10^5 times faster than any other answer. +1

Comment: @pjs `6 * (10**n - 1) / 9`

Comment: @Nick replace `6` with the digit you want.  `(10**n - 1) / 9` is the desired number of 1's, and can then be scaled by any digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ljust** or **rjust**:

```
number = 6
amount_of_times_to_repeat = 30000
big_number = int("".ljust(amount_of_times_to_repeat, str(number)))
print big_number
```

In one single line:

```
print int("".ljust(30000, str(6)))
```

Or:

```
new_number = int("".ljust(30000, str(6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method to generate such numbers with 100000+ digits is `decimal.Decimal()`:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D

d = D('6' * n)
```

Measurements show that `6 * (10**n - 1) // 9` is `O(n*log n)` while `D('6' * n)` is `O(n)`. Though for small `n` (less than ~10000), the former can be faster.

`Decimal` internal representation stores decimal digits directly. If you need to print the numbers latter; [str(Decimal) is much faster than `str(int)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279).